# Grounding a switch that has no ground screw or wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, grounding, timer

I have a timer switch (see photo 1) that has **No Grounding Screw** and ** No Grounding Wire** protruding from it.  It is to be installed into a plastic gang box and replace a switch which is currently grounded by a wire.

The power source for this switch comes from a GFCI circuit.

Should I ground the timer switch by wrapping it around the screw attached to the yoke like the second photo.

Black Hot
White Neutral
Blue Load

[image: Type of switch]

[image: Proposed Solution]

Comment: Does the labeling or instructions authorize installation in a plastic box, is it silent on the matter, or does it have language warning "metal boxes only"?

Comment: It looks to be silent. [Instructions](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-2457EFS.pdf)

Comment: Amazon/ebay/aliexpress special

Comment: This is a honeywell switch it seems, and from what I have read online, it is suggested to ground thru the screw as you have posted in your second image, if it is not a metal box.

Comment: Looking at the docs this looks like a legit item.  Some purchases from Amazon are okay.

Answer (score 1):

I called the company, they didn't seem very knowledgeable. Since the yoke is metal and would be grounded if installed in a metal box. I went ahead and grounded it as between between the box and yoke with the top screw.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a class II product, so it doesn't need grounding.